# Why is the umask number not the same for different local users?

Tags: umask

For one of my local users, "ram", the `umask` is `0002`. Another user, "yas" has the `umask` value `0022` instead.

Shouldn't all users have gotten the same `umask` setting on their creation?

Comment: Did you mess any configuration files?

Comment: No, i dont think so. which file stores the default umask?

Comment: @George The easier way is `grep umask /etc/pam.d/newusers /etc/default/useradd /etc/login.defs /etc/useradd.conf ~ram/.bashrc ~yas/.bashrc`. `grep` can handle multiple files.

Comment: I wanted OP to add that way for better analysis @waltinator.

Comment: Ok run these commands: `grep -i umask /etc/pam.d/newuser`s, `grep -i umask /etc/default/useradd`, `grep UMASK /etc/login.defs` and finally `grep -i umask /etc/adduser.conf` and post the outputs into your question